# How is $-\sin(2x+\pi/2) = -\cos(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am solving double integral $$ \int_0^{\pi} dx \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} cos(2x+y)dy. $$ I am not understanding how is the -sin(2x+pi/2) = -cos(2x) and sin(2x+pi) =  I am aware that sin(pi/2) = 1 rest is unclear to me.

Comment: $\sin(a+b) =\sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a)$.

Comment: How is the double integral related to this question?

Comment: @TehRod Im sorry I made an edit. I was solving double integral when i ran into -sin(2x+pi/2)

Comment: @AlexSilva Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One has
$$
\sin\left(a+\frac{\pi}2\right)=\sin\left(a\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)\cos\left(a\right)=\sin (a) \cdot 0+1\cdot \cos(a)=\cos (a).
$$

Comment: Can you please give me some kind of spreadsheet with all trigonometry rules like that? And thank you for your time

Comment: @DavorMidenjak Sure, let me find it.

Comment: @DavorMidenjak Please have a look at this page:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Symmetry.